# MySQL - Do not allow two rows to have the same specific columns

Tags: mysql

```
id | source | target | desc
--------------------------------------------
0  | hello  | hola   | this is a description   //Valid insert
1  | hello  | no     | this is a description   //Valid insert
2  | what   | what   | desc                    //Valid insert
3  | hello  | hola   | testing                 //INVALID insert
```

I want the row with ID 3 to error when inserted because it's source matches another row's source AND its target matches that same other row's target.

I know that I could do this in PHP, but I would prefer it done within the MySQL RDBMS.

Comment: add unique constraint on columns source and target

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent me from having two rows with the same source? Such as row 0 and 1?

Comment: @Wyatt: Declaring them unique *individually* would. Declaring a *set* of columns unique, however, means you want unique *combinations* of those columns' values.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) ,
  `source` varchar(30) ,
  `target` varchar(30) ,
  `desc` varchar(100) ,
  PRIMARY KEY `pk_id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_source_target` (`source`,`target`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

or on existing table

```
 ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT uc_source_target UNIQUE (`source`,`target`);


INSERT INTO t1
    (`id`, `source`, `target`, `desc`)
VALUES
    (0, 'hello', 'hola', 'this is a description'),
    (1, 'hello', 'no', 'this is a description'),
    (2, 'what', 'what', 'desc');




 mysql>  INSERT INTO t1
    ->            (`id`,`source`,`target`,`desc`)
    ->     VALUES
    ->             (3,'hello','hola','testing');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'hello-hola' for key 'uc_source_target'
```

Comment: Surely, you mean `ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT uq_source_target UNIQUE (source, target);` - note the use of the [UNIQUE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5627dceb2048440553f5a0582e6dd6af) keyword! Typo! :-)

Comment: I forgot that thanks for pointing that out